# prefetch by related_name in children foreign key django

Tags: django, prefetch, django-select-related

i'm trying to prefetch related from parent model to chidren throught the related name, However the queryset in the template still hits the DB in PostgreSQL, my modelB modelC and ModelD all point towards modelA and when I overwrite the generic class based view queryset function it still doesnt affect the size of the query?? any clues ?

```
*MODEL
class ModelA(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(max_lenght=200, null=True, Blank=True)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="model_a_related")

*VIEW
class ModelAView(DetailView):
    model = ModelA

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related('model_a_related')
```

Comment: `.prefetch_related` does *not* fetches the `ModelB`s in the same query, but in a second query. For a `DetailView`, it will not make an improvement: `.prefetch_related` is useful if you render a *set* of `ModelA`s, since then you prevent making a query *per* `ModelA` object to fetch the related `ModelB`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) does *not* fetches the `ModelB`s in the *same* query, but in a *second* query where it fetches all the related `ModelB`s for the selected (filtered) `ModelA`s in bulk, this in contract to fetching it *per* `ModelA` object which would be the usual behavior.

For a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView), it will thus not make any improvement. In a `DetailView` you render a *single* item, and fetching the related `ModelB`s will, regardless whether it is done through `.prefetch_related(…)` or by accessing `object.model_a_related.all()` make *one* extra query.

Comment: Is there a way around to prefetch the data as I think it could be a usefull function for django

Comment: @DrayenDörff: no, the reason `.prefetch_related(..)` was implemented that way is to minimize *bandwidth*: if that would be in the same query, it would produced a lot of duplicate data in the result, and this could eventually lead to hundreds of useless megabytes being transferred from the database to Django.

Comment: so that means that I could reverse the structure to have the modelA pointing to ModelB, that will save a lot of bandwidth, and save me some RAM and CPU usage ?

Comment: @DrayenDörff: if you would use `ModelB.objects.select_related('model_a').filter(model_a__pk=42)`, it will actually result in trouble: indeed, for each record in the result set, it will use exactly the same data for the `model_a` fields, this is why `.prefetch_related` uses another query, to avoid making a query where the same data is *repeated* per record.

Comment: ok so I do a manytomany from modelA to ModelB

Comment: @DrayenDörff: but the modeling should not be done to optimize queries, but to model the data as it is supposed to be. A many-to-many field means that each `ModelA` object can have zero, one or more related `ModelB`s, and that a `ModelB` object can have zero, one or more related `ModelA` objects.